# How can i extract the profiles of people following, liking or commenting my face book page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping, screen-scraping, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to develop a project for which i need to extract information from face book. I started off with the Graph API but it has a lot of limitations on the data that i can scrape from there. The aim is to get the profiles that have engaged in any type of activity with the page by following or liking the page,or have developed an edge by liking or commenting on posts.

The Graph API fails to give the names of the profiles or links to the same. The documentation says that for certain permission and specially for features like page public content access/page public metadata access, an app review is required, however it also mentions that the review is needed when the developer does not have the admin privileges for the page which is not the case here.

The confusion is then why is the API not providing us with the data or why are the metrics not providing the information that they are supposed to. Neither do we get any errors of invalid fields or metrics. The API just says “Field is empty or disallowed by the access token”.

Will the app review help to solve the problem, or are there any other methods that we need to follow.

Also if the API is not helpful here, i read that face book can approve your request of scraping and validate your IP.(i have added the link to the terms of scraping at FB). But i am not sure if this is a good way to proceed. what should i do ?(I can use scrapers with selenium and Beautiful soup but i want to keep this entire process legal)

https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: _“The aim is to get the profiles that […]”_ - and then what? What do you want to _do_ with this information? Facebook does not want you to get this info on a large scale via API, so I doubt they would agree to you scraping it either. (Plus, you’d probably have a hard time finding anyone at Facebook who could give you that permission to begin with. There is no publicly available application form or anything like that, to my knowledge.)

Comment: @CBroe So if there is no way to get your ip approved for scraping then why would Facebook have the TOS terms? Because the terms clearly say what you can do and cannot do with the data you scrape , the link is provided. Also how can face book stop me from getting data about my own page? And if they don't than why do they have fields like FROM and ID in the API under comments field. Also have metrics like post_engaged_fan and permissions like page_read_engagement which allow extraction of the profile names ad id.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/pages_read_engagement

Comment: I did not say there was absolutely no way. But I doubt _you_ will find anyone to talk to about this - no offense, but for that, you will in all likelyhood simply be too small and too unimportant to Facebook. Comments have the from field, yes, but before you can expect to get any data from that for people who do not have a role in the app, you will have to submit it for review and make it live.

Comment: _“and permissions like page_read_engagement which allow extraction of the profile names ad id”_ - it says, _“Get names, PSIDs, and profile pictures of your Page followers”_ - but I wouldn’t know where you’d want to get the followers from in the first place, I don’t know of any endpoint that would return those …?

Comment: @cbroe what about a (non-large scale) scenario where I own the fb page.. And want to simply use the api to analyze and better understand engagements on my own page?

Comment: @CBroe the Page Insights API mentions the link to this endpoint -
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/insights/

Comment: Insights return aggregated numbers, but no individual profile information.

Comment: @CBroe is there any way to get that information from the API or from any other method that is legal ?